# Obtain data in drop down html box using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to get the models in the drop box:

http://www.trademe.co.nz/motors/used-cars/bmw

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 
url="http://www.trademe.co.nz/motors/used-cars/bmw"
r= requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)


price=soup.find("select",{"id":"15"})
options = price.find_all("option")


print(options)
```

Output

```
[<option selected="selected" value="">Any model</option>]
```

I want a list of all the models in the dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data is loaded using ajax. This way when you request the page with python, there is still only one option loaded.

Checking the *Network tab* in the chrome debugger you can get this [url](http://www.trademe.co.nz/API/Ajax/UsedCarsModels.aspx?make=BMW) which returns the models for *BMW*. Now you can requests this url.

```
import requests
url = "http://www.trademe.co.nz/API/Ajax/UsedCarsModels.aspx?make=BMW"
data = requests.get(url).json()
print data['models']
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'